# json data is in dictionary some of values are of different data type and i want insert them in to postgres sql using python

Tags: python, sql, json, psycopg2, psql

Currently :
I am using string concatenation method in python to write values in psql table
Issue : On concatenating a string value with other values  ('') does not appear in the concatenated string so python gives an error (values are in dictionary created from a json file)
Code for entering data into sql

```
       for k in KEYS_NAME:
              KEYS=list(data[k][0].keys())
              Value =list(data[k][0].values())
              if(k!="BMS_Node_Param"):
                     #data[k][0]["u32SWVer"] ="\'"+str(data[k][0]["u32SWVer"])+"\'"
                     if k == 'BMS_Pack':
                            data[k][0]["u32uptime"] ="\'"+str(data[k][0]["u32uptime"])+"\'"
                     check = ",".join(KEYS)
                     val = ",".join(str(V)for V in Value)
                     conn.execute(("INSERT INTO {} ({}) VALUES ({});").format(k,check,val))
```

Comment: If an attacker got access to the JSON file, you're wide open to sql injection. Parameterize your query!

Comment: Could you give an example of your concatenated string and the error? Also as the comment above says this is not a very good way to use a query

Comment: `psycopg2` has [JSON adaption](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#adapt-json) use that. While you are in the docs read [Parameter passing](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) in particular: "Warning Never, never, NEVER use Python string concatenation (+) or string parameters interpolation (%) to pass variables to a SQL query string. Not even at gunpoint. "

Comment: Thank you Everyone @adrian-klaver parameter passing helped me resolve my problem can please tell why string concatenation should never be used

Comment: See [Bobby Tables](https://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: See my 'answer' for demonstration of SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

A simple example of why string concatenation should not be used and how the parameter escaping saves you from SQL injection.

```
import psycopg2 

con = psycopg2.connect("dbname=test user=postgres host=localhost port=5432")    
cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute("create table injection_test(id integer, fld_1 varchar)")
con.commit()

cur.execute("insert into injection_test values (1, 'test'), (2, 'test2')")
con.commit()

cur.execute("select * from injection_test")
cur.fetchall()                                                                                                                                                                                                          
[(1, 'test'), (2, 'test2')]

qry_str = "select * from injection_test where id = 1 " + "; delete from injection_test" 

qry_str = "select * from injection_test where id = 1 " + "; delete from injection_test" 
cur.execute(qry_str)                                                                                                                                                                                                    
con.commit()                                                                                                                                                                                                            
cur.execute("select * from injection_test")                                                                                                                                                                             
cur.fetchall()                                                                                                                                                                                                          
[]

cur.execute("insert into injection_test values (1, 'test'), (2, 'test2')")
con.commit()
qry_str = "select * from injection_test where id = %s " 
cur.execute(qry_str, ["; delete from injection_test"])  

InvalidTextRepresentation: invalid input syntax for type integer: "; delete from injection_test"
LINE 1: select * from injection_test where id = E'; delete from inje...
```