# How to prevent SQL Injections in PostgresSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-injection

Can someone suggest methods to prevent SQL injection in Postgres SQL since I am having trouble understanding what it is and how to prevent it

Comment: You prevent it primarily in your application rather than in the database itself, so of course that will depend on the language you're programming in. See https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp

Comment: See an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71274452/json-data-is-in-dictionary-some-of-values-are-of-different-data-type-and-i-want/71300265#71300265) I wrote earlier this year on this subject.

Comment: How would you prevent it in any other brand of database? That's how you do it in PostgreSQL as well. SQL injection is not about the database itself, it's about what is send to the database, how that is done and how that can be abused.

Comment: This is too broad a question. It is asking at least for a tutorial, not a simple answer.